# Javascript - pre-fill cookie information to bi-pass unnecessary landing pages on a link to an external site.

Tags: javascript, cookies, hyperlink

I have a client who is an independent consultant for a larger organization.

Any shoppers entering the larger organization through her website are tracked and she gets the commission; however, the larger website's user interface to enter the shopping section (I find) is clunky.

They sell adult toys (among other less explicit items), so currently, you have to select the region you are shopping in, then select the field for being over 18, then and only then will you be directed to the shopping section of their website. However, other much more extreme adult product oriented websites do not require ALL of these steps.

Is there a way, therefore, for me to embed cookie information into the link so that when they click my client's link, the shopping region can be pre-selected and the over 18 field can be pre selected, so that, the actual landing page for the end-user IS the actual shopping section that my link was trying to send them to?

The website I have built is http://herbedroomsecrets.com and the 'Shopping' link from within currently send the person to https://josiebisett.yourpassionconsultant.com/splash.asp

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible due to the possible security connotations of giving an external site the ability to set cookies.

If the sites were on the same domain, it would be possible to load the second site within an iFrame and then use javascript to click the button(s), but sadly that is not the case.